# Is there a scripting interface for the new type of dock-able floating panels in GMS3?

Tags: dm-script

In GMS3, there seems to be a new kind of floating palette that can be subdivided and has a wider area for UI elements (e.g. Display and Technique Manager).  Can such UI panels be generated via DM scripts?  The floating panels generated via DLGCreateDialog and RegisterScriptPalette are narrower and have more limited docking behavior, so it seems that it would be beneficial to be able to generate panels that follow the new UI model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these panels ("Technique panels") are currently (GMS 3.1) not supported by script.